# Prefetch apple-touch-icon before adding to home screen

Tags: html, ios, progressive-web-apps, apple-touch-icon

Before adding a Web App to the home screen, a popup comes up to confirm the PWA's (Progressive Web App) name and icon. Initially, the icon displays as a screenshot of the current page. When the image finally loads, the icon here...

`<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="appleicon.png">`

...fades in and replaces the screenshot. Is anyone aware of a way to "prefetch" or "preload" this icon before saving it to home screen?

I'm trying to remove the awkward screenshot that displays before the image is downloaded.

So far, rendering the image in an `<img >` tag does not work.

Thanks